# Make a class an instance of another class

Tags: class, haskell, instance

I have a class called `Foo` that owns a function `gen :: Int -> [Foo]`. For instance, I could make an instance of `Foo` that way:

```
data FooTest = FooTest Int

instance Foo FooTest where
  gen n = replicate n (FooTest 0)
```

Now, let’s imagine I have another class called `Bar` that defines a function `bar :: Bar -> IO ()`. Each instance of `Foo` has to be an instance of `Bar`, **but** the `Bar` implementation is quite the same for each instance. Here’s an example:

```
class Foo f where
  gen :: Int -> [f]

class Bar b where
  bar :: b -> IO ()

instance Bar Foo where -- obviously that doesn’t work
  bar _ = putStrLn "bar through any Foo instance"

instance (Foo f) => Bar f where -- this needs the FlexibleInstance GHC extension first, then it still throws shit saying that the constraint is not smaller that I don’t shit
  bar _ = putStrLn "bar through any Foo instance"
```

The problem here is I can’t find any ways to make a class an instance of another to mention the fact that any instance of the first class will share the same implementation for instancing the other class.

Any idea?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can accomplish exactly what you want using your last instance with *two* extensions: `FlexibleInstances` and `UndecidableInstances`.

Just like the name implies, the second extension allows you to potentially write instances that do not terminate. This could lead to an infinite loop at compile time; however, the implementation is arbitrarily capped at a certain recursion depth, so you should not have actually infinite compile times.

I do not know of any way to do this without any extensions at all. However, using extensions is not inherently bad unless you might want to use other compilers in the future.

Also, a random style note: the parentheses are optional if you only have one constraint. So you could write it as:

```
instance Foo f => Bar f where ...
```

This isn't very important, but I think the second version looks better.

Comment: thanks a lot! Just for my knowledge, what is `FlexibleInstance` for? Do the two extensions work in pair?

Comment: I consistently write parentheses around all contexts.  That makes type signatures and class/instance heads more readable.  So I don't agree with your style note.

Comment: Regarding FlexibleInstaces: See also this QA: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8367423/are-haskell-flexibleinstances-a-stable-extension-to-the-language